# API and motherboard

Tags: api, software, hardware

I'm new on API and still undergoing some research to gain knowledge for my presentations for next few days.

Different motherboard have different CPU socket. 
So I was just wondering, do API affect the different kind of CPU that only compatible with their own motherboard?

Like for example, (I don't know if this is true or not) AM4 motherboard only compatible with AMD's CPU because of the API integrated within the motherboard.

I hope my question get through.

Thanks

Comment: The [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) can indeed be unaware of newer chips, and thus not work with them without a reflash with updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing two fairly different realms of the overall computing system.

APIs are fairly high level constructs, built over many layers of abstraction.

Motherboards and CPUs are way, way down the abstraction rabbit hole. So much so that for probably 99% of developers, CPU and motherboard related details are completely invisible and irrelevant.

AM4 mobos can only use AM4 CPUs for a variety of reasons. The CPU has to match the physical dimensions of the socket, the electrical interface has to be compliant, the functions of each of the 1331 pins have to be exactly correct, and none of that happens by accident.

There really isn't an "API" for CPUs, unless you really stretch the meaning of API. Instead, CPUs rather have [Instruction Sets.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) Virtually all desktops nowadays have the x86 and it's younger sibling x64 instruction sets. However, there are a variety of extensions to the x86 instructions, such as SSE, MMX, x64, etc.

The system needs to be able to interrogate a processor to find out what is present on a chip, and different manufacturers have different ways of doing that, and don't necessarily bother to share that with each other. Back in the late 90s you could use both Intel or AMD and other chips in the same motherboard.

Once the system is up and running and the BIOS has initialized all of the hardware, there is little difference between different hardware, except to the OS kernel responsible for abstracting that hardware. Once you get into userland writing application software, the hardware is further made invisible.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that some "peripherals" can't even escape this, instead being controlled via the instruction set as well. It's hard to do much with an x86 without using memory I/O, but that I/O has to start off operating for the BIOS to bootstrap to full functionality...

Comment: @aerohammer: given the level of confusion the OP is showing, covering those kind of details would not help.

Answer (score 1):

Usually `API` means **A**pplication **P**rogramming **I**nterface and has no relation to hardware CPU socket on motherboard.

CPU socket on motherboard is like wall electric power socket or headphone audio connector on mobile phone. It is **electrically** compatible to device it is designed for only.